# Change Python long file paths option

Tags: python, windows

I just installed Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10. I was offered the option to enable long file paths but there was no information about why or whether this was a good idea, so I chose not to. Now I want to enable that option - how do  do that please? I want the exact same effect as selecting the option at installation would have had.

I tried "repair installation" in hopes of seeing the option again, but no luck.

Comment: You can delete python and reinstall again, **if you want**

Comment: The application manifest of python[w].exe in 3.6+ declares the process to be long-path aware. So the only setting that needs to be enabled is the system "LongPathsEnabled" policy in the registry key "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem". With this policy set, all long-path aware applications can use long DOS paths with most filesystem functions. The system does not have to be restarted for this to take effect, since each process individually checks this policy at startup.

Comment: There's one ugly wart with this feature. The working directory in a long-path enabled process supports long DOS paths, but the working directory of child processes is still initially limited to `MAX_PATH - 2` characters (i.e. 258 characters, plus a trailing backslash and null). If the working directory is a longer path, `CreateProcessW` will fail with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (87) if the child's working directory is the default setting that inherits the parent's working directory (e.g. `lpCurrentDirectory=NULL` with `CreateProcessW` -- or `cwd=None` with Python's `subprocess.Popen`).